# How to sum the value of the current cell with the value of another cell each time using a macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I want C3 to show C3+B3 every time I run the macro
And when I change the value of the B3, I want it to be summed up with the last value in C3

Example:
B3 is 15
C3 is 0

I run the macro

It turns out like this

B3 is 15
C3 is 15

I change the value of B3

B3 is 25
C3 is still 15

I run the macro again

It would turn out like this

B3 is 25
C3 is 40

Ive used the current macro for summing, but It doesnt work in this case...

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Range("C3").Formula = "=Sum(C3, B3)"
End Sub
```

It keeps saying end of object error or sth...

I appreciate any suggestions or alternative routes to solve my problem...

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Ok, Added up stuff..

Comment: Why did you set it up as a formula, why not just `Range("C3") =  Range("C3") + Range("B3")`

Comment: Thanks!!! I really appreciate it!!!! It worked!!!! Im a rookie in writing macros. So sorry!!! LOL

Comment: @MátéJuhász Please write up a solution. Fantasy Hero, please accept the answer to close this question so nobody tries to solve this further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't want it to be automatically updated, don't use `Range.Formula`, also `SUM`'s syntax wasn't correct:

`Range("C3") = Range("C3") + Range("B3")`